# WHERE conditions on same column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a following query which has multiple conditions on the same field. It is working fine but not sure if this is a right way to do it.

I want to display all transactions from certain date, also if customer has link date then ignore transactions which were done prior to link date.

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME = '2019/03/09 00:01:57.000'

    SELECT  
        f.[OID] ,
        f.[CustomerNum] ,
        f.[Amount] ,
        f.[TransactionDate] ,
        cus.Linkdate            
FROM    [Transaction] f
INNER JOIN dbo.Customer cus ON cus.CusNum = f.CustomerNum AND cus.OID = f.OID
WHERE   f.OID = 16 AND f.CustomerNum = 1234
        AND f.TransactionDate > @Date
        AND f.TransactionDate >= ISNULL(cus.Linkdate,@Date)
```

Comment: How big is your data?  You may want to consider using a temp table to first filter out for your LinkDate and then run remaining predicates on the temp data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is fine, but I prefer phrasing it as:

```
WHERE f.OID = 16 AND
      f.CustomerNum = 1234 AND
      f.TransactionDate > @Date AND
      (cus.LinkDate IS NULL OR f.TransactionDate >= cus.Linkdate)
```

I find that this better conveys the intention of the logic.